# Show Message Box After Button Click

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to show a QMessage.information box after a button has been clicked. I have tried to implement it but It does not seem to be working. Here is a copy of my code and the stack trace. What am I doing wrong, what is the correct way to do this in order to display a message box after the button has been clicked.

```
# Main Class that holds User Interface Objects
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    # Function for Opening Report Viewer Window From Main Window by clicking View Reports button
    def openReportViewer(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_reportViewerWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()



    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(834, 428)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        # Sim Card Button
        self.simCardButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.simCardButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 211, 30))
        self.simCardButton.setToolTip("Select to parse sim card data")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.simCardButton.setFont(font)
        self.simCardButton.setObjectName("simCardButton")

        # Call Logs Button
        self.callLogButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.callLogButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 300, 211, 30))
        self.callLogButton.setToolTip("Select to parse call log data")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.callLogButton.setFont(font)
        self.callLogButton.setObjectName("callLogButton")

        # SMS Button
        self.smsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.smsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 250, 211, 30))
        self.smsButton.setToolTip("Select to parse sms data")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smsButton.setFont(font)
        self.smsButton.setObjectName("smsButton")

        # Canonical Address Button
        self.canonicalAddressesButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 211, 30))
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setToolTip("Select to parse canonical address data")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setFont(font)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setObjectName("canonicalAddressesButton")

        # Main Window Label
        self.windowMainLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.windowMainLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 20, 423, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.windowMainLabel.setFont(font)
        self.windowMainLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.windowMainLabel.setObjectName("windowMainLabel")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 291, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        # Combo Box settings
        self.ViewDataCB = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ViewDataCB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 150, 231, 22))
        self.ViewDataCB.setToolTip("Choose data report type")
        self.ViewDataCB.setObjectName("ViewDataCB")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("canonical address")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("sim card")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("sms")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("call logs")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("choice prompt")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("full report")

        # # View Evidence Button
        self.viewReportsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.viewReportsButton.setFont(font)
        self.viewReportsButton.setObjectName("viewReportsButton")



        # Label for evidence viewer
        self.evidenceViewingLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 120, 141, 16))
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setObjectName("evidenceViewingLabel")
        self.generateReportButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generateReportButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 320, 141, 31))
        self.generateReportButton.setObjectName("generateReportButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionOpen_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_2.setObjectName("actionOpen_2")
        self.actionExit_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit_2.setObjectName("actionExit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    # Function that sets the text on all the UI Buttons
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "SQLite DB Android Parser"))
        self.simCardButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sim Card"))
        self.callLogButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Call Logs"))
        self.smsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS "))
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Addresses"))
        self.windowMainLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SQLite Android Database Parser"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Please Choose Data Parsing Option"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Choose An Option"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Address Report"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Sim Card Report"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "SMS Report"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Call Log Report"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "Full Evidence Report"))
        self.viewReportsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "View Reports"))
        self.viewReportsButton.setToolTip("Select to open report viewing window")
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Report Generator"))
        self.generateReportButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Generate Report"))
        self.generateReportButton.setToolTip("Select to generate report")
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionOpen_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))

    # Event Handling Code Section

        # Event Handling to open Report Viewer Window
        self.viewReportsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 360, 141, 31))
        self.viewReportsButton.clicked.connect(self.openReportViewer)

        # Canonical Addresses Button click functionality to parse canonical address data
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.select_canonical_data)

        # Sim Card Button click functionality to parse sim card data
        self.simCardButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sim_data)

        # Call Logs Button click functionality to parse call log data
        self.callLogButton.clicked.connect(self.select_call_data)

        # SMS Button click functionality to parse SMS data
        self.smsButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sms_data)



    w = QWidget
    # Canonical Addresses button function
    def select_canonical_data(self):
        os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')
    canonical_message_box = QMessageBox.information(w, "Message",'Canonical Address Data Generated')
    w.show()


    # call log button function
    def select_call_data(self):
        os.system('CallLogParser.py')

    # sms button function
    def select_sms_data(self):
        os.system('SmsParser.py')

    # sim card button function
    def select_sim_data(self):
        os.system('SimCardParser.py')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


Stack Trace

 canonical_message_box = QMessageBox.information(w, "Message",'Canonical Address Data Generated')
TypeError: QMessageBox.information(QWidget, str, str, QMessageBox.StandardButtons buttons=QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.StandardButton defaultButton=QMessageBox.NoButton): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are making an empty widget (`w = QWidget`) and then assigning it as the parent of the QMessageBox dialog.  This needs to be an instance of your MainWindow class.  Something like this:

```
self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.select_canonical_data(MainWindow))
# The lambda is necessary in this circumstance to supply the MainWindow instance to your method

def select_cannonical_data(self):
    os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')
    canonical_message_box = QMessageBox.information(w, "Message",'Canonical Address Data Generated')
    # Your indention is wrong on the above line in your code
```

This code will open the dialog for you, but this is really not an ideal way to set this up.  You seem to be having a lot of trouble with this particular code.  I have seen several of your questions about this exact same piece of code.  I would recommend that you spend some time with some PyQt5 tutorials to learn more about how to properly use it and maybe research a little more before asking so many questions here.  Most of what you have asked can be easily found with very minimal research.

Comment: I have been researching @MalloyDelacroix but I cannot seem to get it to work. I have look at numerous examples of how to implement this and it has not worked.

Comment: [Here is a tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/deepaksingh04/design-simple-dialog-using-pyqt5-designer-tool-ajskrd09n) that I think may be helpful.  Right now it looks like you are setting up your gui in the file generated by using the pyuic tool on a .ui file created with QtDesigner.  You usually do not want to edit this file, but import its Ui_ class into another file from which you build the gui interactions.  This tutorial shows one way in which to do this.  I would recommend starting there and then looking for some more in depth tutorials.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have decided I want to leave this functionality for now and come back to it later when other more important parts of the system are coded such as error handling etc.